# Integral of $\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}$ over unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need to compute

$$\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz$$

here $\gamma$ is the unit circle. I have by a Corollary out of Conways Complex Variables VI that

$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}}dw$$

Thus

$$\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz = \frac{2 \pi i}{1!}f^{(1)}(0)=-2 \pi$$

Did I compute it correctly?

Comment: Looks good. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BExp%5Bi+Exp%5Bi+q%5D%5D%2FExp%5Bi+q%5D%5E2*i+Exp%5Bi+q%5D%2C%7Bq%2C0%2C2Pi%7D%5D) comes up with the same thing.

Comment: sweet, thanks! @eyeballfrog

Comment: What is $f$? What is $n$? Why not write$$e^{iz}=1+iz-\frac 12z^2-\frac i6z^3+\dots$$then divide by $z^2$, and isolate the residual part, the one in $\frac 1z$... ?!

Comment: my $f(z):=e^{iz}$ and my $n=1$, @dan_fulea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its right. A way to see it is differentiating under the integral sign (so you dont need to remember a formula for it), that is

$$
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}(z ,\epsilon )} \frac{f(\zeta )}{\zeta -z}d\zeta =f(z)\\
\implies \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}(z ,\epsilon )} \frac{f(\zeta )}{\zeta -z}d\zeta\right)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}(z,\epsilon )}\frac{f(\zeta )}{(\zeta -z)^2}d\zeta =f'(z)
$$

Therefore

$$
\oint \frac{e^{i\zeta }}{\zeta ^2}d\zeta =\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\bigg|_{z=0}\oint \frac{e^{i\zeta }}{\zeta -z}d\zeta =\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\bigg|_{z=0}\left(2\pi i \cdot e^{iz}\right)=-2\pi
$$